# Genericパラメーターが不定のクラスの配列の作り方

Tags: swift

```
class Foo<T> {}

class Bar {
    var foos = [Foo]()
}
```

上記のようにすると "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" というエラーが出てコンパイルが通りません。

```
var foos = [Foo<String>]()
```

のようにGenericパラメーターを定めればコンパイルは通りますが、Tの型に関わらずFooを保持することはできないでしょうか？
（Javaのワイルドカード指定、Foo<*>のような扱い方）

別途プロトコルを作ってFooに実装するしかないでしょうか？